# Http request not fetching based on the parameter in angular .There is something wrong with the params

Tags: javascript, angular, http, parameters

this is the iposts interface I am using

```
export interface IPosts
{
        albumId: number,
        id: number,
        title: string,
        url: string,
        thumbnailUrl: string
}
```

this is the function call i am making to the service

```
  ngOnInit() {


this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params : ParamMap) =>
{
  let id = parseInt(params.get('id'));
  this.ProductId = id;

  this.PostService.getPostsByParam(id).subscribe(data => this.States = data);

});
```

this is the url i am requesting to

```
private _url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';
```

this is my request function which is getting the id  and  i want to request on based of id as param

```
getPostsByParam(id:number):Observable<IPosts[]>
  {
    let params1 =  new HttpParams().set("id",'id');
    return this.http.get<IPosts[]>(this._url,{params:params1});
  }
```

this is the html code

```
<div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="let state of States" class="card col-lg-2"  style="width: 18rem; ">

             <img class="card-img-top" src="{{state.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">{{state.title}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
          <br/>
    </div>
```

Comment: use this instead `return this.http.get<IPosts[]>(this._url,{id: 'id'});`

Comment: do you want to call `'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/id'`??

Comment: yes i want to call that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, instead of using a query parameter, you could use the ID as the  end-point of the URL. So you could directly append it to the end of it.

```js
getPostsByParam (id:number): Observable<IPosts[]> {
  return this.http.get<IPosts[]>(this._url + '/' + id);  // <-- append `id` here
}
```

But the response obtained isn't an array that could be looped over. It is a single object. If you need the array of all the objects, the URL must be called without any ID.

Also you could replace the inner subscription with a RxJS [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) and a single subscription.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap(params => {
      const id = parseInt(params.get('id'));
      this.ProductId = id;
      return this.PostService.getPostsByParam(id);
    }))
    .subscribe(
      data => { this.States = data },
      error => { // always good practice to handle HTTP errors }
    );
}
```

Comment: i am getting a single error now about how i am accessiing it . Can you suggest a way to access it in html without using array

Comment: Could you please say what error you're getting now? If you're using an `id`, then it retrieves one single object. So you could remove the `*ngFor` directive and access the properties directly in the template using `{{ States.url }}`, `{{ States.title }}`. If you wish to display all the states with the `*ngFor`, then you need to remove the `id` from the HTTP call.

Comment: <p class="card-text">{{states.title}}</p> i added the title now like this but the error i am getting is Cannot read property 'title' of undefined and no i need to display only the one i fected using id i am getting the object in states for the id i requested for but i donno maybe its not assigning it to the main states value

Comment: sorry my bad it works now thank you so much . I will mark this as done :)

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of

```
let params1 =  new HttpParams().set("id",'id');
    return this.http.get<IPosts[]>(this._url,{params:params1});
```

do like this:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('id', id.toString());
  return this.http.get<IPosts[]>this._url, { params: params })
```